# Is there a WebView On Navigation method?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a WebView that loads a certain URL, on loading I set some cookies to the website. I noticed if the user clicks any link on the website, the cookies I set don't effect the new page. Is there a way to set the cookies every time there is a page navigation? This is my code to set the cookies.

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.setCookie("URL HERE", "COOKIES HERE");
```

And upon navigation I am planning to use the following code to set the cookies for the new page.

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

cookieManager.setCookie(browser.getUrl(), "My Cookies");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. You can use the following code inside onCreate Method.

```
final WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient( ) {

                @Override
                public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {

                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
                cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
                cookieManager.setCookie("URL HERE, "COOKIES HERE");

                }

            });
```